# PHP: List of all function Grouped by class

Tags: php, class, function

I am looking for a way to get a list of all the php functions but needed them group by the class they exist in. Not sure if there is a way to get this from PHP docs or if its built into PHP. I am really only looking for built in / popular classes, so a custom mysqli class I dont care about but the mysql library that can be installed with PHP I do need.

Thank you very much

Comment: `get_declared_classes()` + `ReflectionClass` and a little bit of work will get you there... `mysql` is not a class though.

Comment: Look towards to `Reflection`, `get_declared_functions`, `get_declared_classes`, and software like `PHPDocumentor`

Comment: Many built-in and extension functions are not members of classes, but are prefixed like `mysql_`. those will be listed in groups via `get_defined_functions()`.

Comment: Haven't done any work in PHP myself, but from a quick view of the documentation it seems like `get_class_methods` might do what you want.

Comment: @deceze I meant mysqli

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
foreach(get_declared_classes() as $classname) {
    echo $classname . PHP_EOL;
    $class = new ReflectionClass($classname);
    foreach($class->getMethods() as $m) {
        echo '  ' . $m->name . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I'm using [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) to get a list of all declared classes. Then I create a [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) object from them and iterate throught their methods.